# Multiselect Rails 3, Default Selections with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, multi-select

I have a Rails 3 application where I allow the user to apply tags to their listing. I've read a few stackoverflow threads with similar questions but this one is unique since I am using a frontend framework. I am using the webarch framework: http://www.revox.io/webarch/form_elements.html

If you CTRL + F "Multi Select" you can see the exact element that I am using.

**Summary**

I use this code to populate tags:

```
<%= f.collection_select :tag_ids, Tag.all, :id, :name, {:selected => @listing.tags.map(&:id).map(&:to_i)}, { :multiple => true, :style => "width:100%", :id => "multi", :class => "select2-offscreen", :placeholder => "Select Tags."  } %>
```

This works to assign tags, but the tags that have already been saved to a listing do not appear in the dropdown on the edit view. For example, if the a user has tagged their listing as "Jim" and "Lucy", they should see this when they arrive on the edit view.

[image: image of desired dropdown]

**Framework's JS code**

The framework is added to the site. In the JS files, it has the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      //Dropdown menu - select2 plug-in
      $("#source").select2();

      //Multiselect - Select2 plug-in
      $("#multi").val(["Jim","Lucy"]).select2();
```

This is excellent starting logic, but obviously I don't want "Jim" "Lucy" manually coded into my dropdowns. How can I override this in js to make it work correctly for the existing tags?

```
{:selected => @listing.tags.map(&:id).map(&:to_i)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to go into the plugin's files and change the code to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     //Dropdown menu - select2 plug-in
     $("#source").select2();

     //Multiselect - Select2 plug-in
     var multi = $("#multi");
     var selected = multi.find("option[selected]").map(function() { return this.value; });
     multi.val(selected).select2();
```